# React Button with linkto functionality add option

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React Button component which currently has a prop where you add a page to link for.

This works fine but I want to add a new prop called 'type' so the button can either link to another page (like it does now),
or execute an onclick event ... for example execute a function when clicked.

Here's the current code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link to={this.props.linkto}>{this.props.text}</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Button;
```

Usage:

```
<Button linkto={'about'} text={'my button'} />
```

This button currently will only navigate to another page using the react-router.

I'd like to have to option to add a 'Type' property so that I can either have the button Navigate like it is now or '**onclick**' so I can execute a function.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you also need to pass the function with type prop?

Comment: yes, if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass 'type' prop with a function or link. Then you can check with ternary operator whether the passed prop was the function, and invoke it if true. Just make sure that you bind your function in the component where you are including the Button component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import isfunction from 'lodash.isfunction';

    class Button extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            {isfunction(this.props.type) ? <button onClick={() => this.props.type()} /> : <Link to={this.props.linkto}>{this.props.text}</Link>}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Button;
```

Will render Link component:

```
<Button linkto={'about'} text={'my button'} type={link}/>
```

Will render button with on click funtion:

```
<Button linkto={'about'} text={'my button'} type={someFuntion} />
```

Comment: I was thinking of using 'type' just to pass the 'type' for example: type={link} or type={click} and depending on the type use linkto or onclick ..does it make sense?

Comment: For example for click type I would do: <Button type={click} text={my button} onclick={myfunction} />

Comment: Or if type - link ... <Button type={link} text={my button} linkto={about} />

Comment: Yes it can be done either by checking whether the passed prop is function type, or adding a new prop to let the component know which type it is.

Comment: I have updated my answer you will need to add Lodash isfunction module. https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.isfunction